# Laravel 5.6 Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Auth\\GenericUser::withAccessToken()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to access an API endpoint that requires access token. I have generated an access token using $u->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken successfuly but when I try to access the endpoint I get error below:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::withAccessToken()", "exception":
>   "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"

**Route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::get('/details/{user}', 'SignupController@allInvites');
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function allInvites(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user;
    $data = Posts::allInvites($user);
    // returns number of invites
    return response()->json($data, 200);
}
```

**Postman**

[image]

**User Providers - Auth.php**

Not using eloquent

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'users',
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Comment: Have you added `use HasApiTokens;` to your user class?

Comment: Yes I called it

Comment: it means there is no method such as `withAccessToken()
` in GenericUser class.. Also are you sure that you're using correct namespace ? Why there are double backslashes in the namespace ?

Comment: Can you post the top of the User class that you are using? `HasApiTokens` is a trait so needs to be called *within* the class, not before it.

Comment: What do you have set in `auth/config.php` under the API guard?

Comment: I set:         'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

Comment: I got the same problem, have solved it? I have this issue on github https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/970